# Weak formulation, divergence free

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I was trying to find the weak formulation of the following problem

\begin{align} 
-\vartheta\Delta u + b \cdot \nabla u &= f \quad \text{in $\Omega$} \\
u &= 0 \quad \text{in $\partial \Omega$}
\end{align}

where $b:\bar{\Omega}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, b\in C^1(\Omega)$ is a divergence free velocity field. I have computed the weak formulation by multiplying both sides with a test function and integrating over the domain. I have

\begin{equation} 
a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} \vartheta \nabla u \cdot \nabla v+ (b \cdot \nabla u)  v
\end{equation}

Is this done? I don't know how to use the fact that $b$ is divergence free.
Next I wanted to show that the bilinear form is bounded. Normally I would try and do this using the $L^2$ Norm and a Sobolev Inequality $\|u\| \leq C\|Du\|$. But I feel I am doing something wrong because it is not working.

Comment: Do you mean $b \color{red}{\cdot} \nabla u$? And the term in your bilinear form should be $\nabla u \color{red}{\cdot} \nabla v$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Note that $$\int (b \cdot \nabla u) v = \int [\nabla \cdot(b u) - u \underbrace{\nabla \cdot b}_{=0}] v = \int v \nabla \cdot(bu)$$ and then use the divergence theorem/integrate by parts.

Comment: Your bilinear form is bounded on $H^1_0$. Try Hoelder inequality.

Comment: Now I got \begin{equation} 
a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} \vartheta \nabla u \cdot \nabla v- (bu)\cdot \nabla  v
\end{equation}
is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blf as in the comment, i.e.,

$$a(u,v) = \int_\Omega \vartheta \nabla u \cdot \nabla v -\int_\Omega (bu) \cdot \nabla v $$

for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ is correct. It is bounded in $H_0^1 \times H_0^1$ since

$$\begin{aligned}|a(u,v)| &\leq \vartheta \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}  \|\nabla v\|_{L^2} + \|b\|_{L^\infty} \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
&\leq (\vartheta+\|b\|_{L^\infty}) \|u\|_{H^1} \|v\|_{H^1}. 
\end{aligned}$$